# I want to put Ubuntu on my middle-aged laptop

Tags: system-installation

Ive never put an OS on anything before. My brother in law wiped my entire OS off laptop, when he was certain he was just doing a factory reset! It HAD windows 10. Now, it has a black screen and a blinking cursor... please help

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview